# C: SDL Code compiling in ubuntu terminal but not in vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compilation, sdl

When I compile my code in the ubuntu terminal, it compiles perfectly, but when I execute the command in the VSCode integrated terminal, it gives me an error:

```
main.c:1:10: fatal error: no such file or directory
```

here's the command I use:

```
$ gcc main.c $(sdl2-config --cflags --libs) -o prog
```

and here is my code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    SDL_Window *window = NULL;

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        SDL_Log("ERROR: SDL Initialization > %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
    
    

    // program execution
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2 Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, 0);
    
    if(window == NULL) {
        SDL_Log("ERROR: SDL Initialization > %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
    }
    SDl_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What OS is VSCode running on? Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: My first impression was that retrieving the config flags might fail but the error message looks as if you try to execut `main.c` itself. That's a bit strange